# CSS - How to remove whitespace between anchored images

Tags: html, css, anchor, image

I have two anchored images on top of each other, separated with a line break.  I want the images to sit directly on top of each other, but in Firefox there is a gap between the images. It works in IE7. The only way I have been able to fix this is by changing the line-height (which I don't want to do).

```
<a href="image.jpg">
    <img height="75" width="75" src="image.jpg" />
</a>
<br/>
<a href="image2.jpg">
    <img height="75" width="75" src="image2.jpg" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placing the CSS property vertical-align to bottom on the top image will remove the gap in Firefox.

Comment: Glad I could help -- oddly enough it trips me up for a couple of minutes every time.

Comment: Edit: bottom, middle, or top works as long as it's applied to ALL of the images.  I wish you could edit comments on SO :)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps setting the images to `display:block` would work. As an image is by default inline with the text, it leaves space at the bottom for descendenders (such as j,g,and y), even though an image will never have any. Many browsers account for this, but doing so is non-standard. Setting them to `block` should remove this annoyance in all browsers.