# Space between anchor image within table data

Tags: css, image, gaps-in-visuals

Table data has border and a link image and some other anchor text below it.

The problem is it has space between link, the solution I get from this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111783/css-how-to-remove-whitespace-between-anchored-images) simply use vertical-align which remove the gap between anchor (which works) but in my case it create a gap between border-top td border and anchor image instead. Using clear both doesnt work too. Any idea?

```
  <td style="font-size:14px;border:1px solid #848484;font-weight: bold;">
      <a target="_BLANK" href=""><img style="border:none;" src="clothing.jpg" alt="Female Clothing"/></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="">&nbsp; &raquo;  Sub Men</a>
   </td>
```

Comment: won't you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @yair [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cG4Jp/1/) but it works on that jsfiddle, I dont see any gap between border-top and image after using vertical-align:top. But how to remove the gap between Cloth and border bottom of td?

Comment: Gap is your border-bottom:1px solid white

Comment: @Radio u r right on that money, I should be careful what code I have put. I will recheck for the gap on the border-top for the image and table data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have to use both vertical align and display block in order to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to set:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: current set up is cellspacing of 10 and cellpadding 0. However since the links are within the same <td> cellspacing wont affect it (tried), only affect the space between table data.